# elasticsearch snapshot are not being published on azure storage account

Tags: elasticsearch

I implemented to setup  elasticsearch Backup and Restore From Azure Blob Storage but When i am running the below query I am getting the response as "acknowledged" but when i check the storage account, I dont see the backups

```
PUT _snapshot/azure-kibana
{
  "type": "azure",
  "settings": {
    "container": "elasticsearch-snapshots",
    "chunk_size": "32MB",
    "compress": true
  }
}
```

output

```
#! Deprecation: Elasticsearch built-in security features are not enabled. Without authentication, your cluster could be accessible to anyone. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/security-minimal-setup.html to enable security.
{
  "acknowledged" : true
}
GET /_snapshot/_all
#! Deprecation: Elasticsearch built-in security features are not enabled. Without authentication, your cluster could be accessible to anyone. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/security-minimal-setup.html to enable security.
    {
      "my_backup" : {
        "type" : "fs",
        "settings" : {
          "location" : "/home/ubuntu/mount/backup"
        }
      },
      "azure-kibana" : {
        "type" : "azure",
        "settings" : {
          "container" : "elasticsearch-snapshots",
          "compress" : "true",
          "chunk_size" : "32MB"
        }
      },
      "azure-kibana2" : {
        "type" : "azure",
        "settings" : {
          "container" : "test",
          "compress" : "true"
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled the plugin and did the setup again, now my snapshots are visible in the storage account